# Storing site style using Local web storage API and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, getelementbyid

i have three functions which will change my pages style. I need to use the local storage api to have these styles remain on the page when i refresh or leave the page and comeback.

This is one of the styles for example:

```
function style1(){
    var vP = document.getElementById('video_container');
    var bG = document.getElementsByTagName('body');
    var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
    var banner = document.getElementById('top_header');
    var body = document.getElementById('body_div');

    vP.style.backgroundColor = ('black');
    bG[0].style.background = "url('images/bg/bg1.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed";
    sidebar.style.display = ('block');  
    banner.style.display = ('block'); 
    body.style.marginTop = ('190px');   
}
```

This is what I've written trying to store the chosen style:

```
window.addEventListener('load',initiate);
window.addEventListener('beforeunload',newItem);

function initiate(){
    var f1 = document.getElementById('f1');
    var f2 = document.getElementById('f2');
    var f3 = document.getElementById('f3');

    f1.addEventListener('click',newItem(f1));
    f2.addEventListener('click',newItem(f2));
    f3.addEventListener('click',newItem(f3));

    window.addEventListener('storage', storagechange);
    show(id);
}

function newItem(x){
    var id = getElementById(x);
    var style =  id.getAttribute('onclick');
    localStorage.setItem(id,style);
    show(id);
}
function show(){   
    localStorage.getItem(id);
}
```

This the list contain the style in HTML :

```
<div id="sideMenu" >
    <ul class="bmenu">
        <li id="f1" onclick="style1()">Style 1</li> <!--turn sidebar on/off-->
        <li id='f2' onclick="style2()">Style 2</li> <!--randomize vidcontain border-->
        <li id='f3' onclick="style3()">Style 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```